# How to solve lacked sufficient buffer in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting this error what is solution of this can anyone tell me please.
and the file is correct this is working fine.

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): An operation on a socket could not be performed because 
the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full. in
C:\wamp\www\pravin_update_utoo_msg_UI\functions\config.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Windows operating system problem with a lot of possible causes and solutions. Your best bet is to Google it.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+system+lacked+sufficient+buffer+space+or+because+a+queue+was+full%22